# React native back button missing icon

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing a react native module for an existing mobile app, using react-navigation component:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
....

const App = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: Main,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerBackTitle: null,
        }
    },
    Details: {
        screen: Details,
        navigationOptions: {
           headerBackTitle: null,
        }
    }

});
```

In Main index I render a simple button that on click do this:

```
render() {

        const navigation = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    title="Go to details"
                    onPress={() => { navigation.navigate("Details") }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

That's it.

The issue is that the navigation back button is invisible (see image):

[image]

This happen after this operations:

- Copying bundle in android project .

  ```
  react-native bundle --platform android \
  --dev false --entry-file index.js 
  --bundle-output ../MyApp/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest ../MyApp/app/src/main/
  ```
- Launching app from Android studio

Any advice?

Comment: So it works but is invisible? It might be that it is white per default and the background is as well. Try to change the color of the background with `headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
      },`, or change the color of your Button with: `<Button color={'black'} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerLeft: drawerButton(navigation)
})

const drawerButton = navigation => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerToggle")}>
        <Image source={Your.image} style={Your.Style} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Use this code!

Comment: Nice, but what if I want to render default iOS headerLeft?

Comment: You caaaan't <3

Comment: @LucaDavanzo If you're still interested, use `headerBackButton` from `react-navigation-stack`.