# Back Icon in StackNavigator doesn't appear - React Native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I tried to write a function to create Stack Navigator in React Native. Everything works fine but there's no back icon to navigate back for stack of Home and of Info. Anyone can help please?

In generateNav.js: function to create StackNavigator

```
const generateNav = (title, menu) => {
    var route = {}
    var param = {}
    route[title] = {
        screen: ViewMenu, 
        params: { menu: menu}
    }

    param['initialRouteName'] = title
    // to get rid of white space at the top of application
    param['headerMode'] = 'none'
    param['navigationOptions'] = { 'headerBackTitle': title }

    return (createStackNavigator(route, param))
}

export { generateNav }
```

In navigation.js: to create BottomTabNavigator, including 2 stack navigators (HomeNavigator, InfoNavigator)

```
const HomeNavigator = generateNav(Home, homeMenu)
const InfoNavigator = generateNav(Info, infoMenu)

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: HomeNavigator },
        Info: { screen: InfoNavigator }
    }
)
```

In ViewMenu.js: to render lists of stack navigators. And I need to have a back icon when clicking on each item.

```
export default class ViewMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.menu = this.props.navigation.getParam('menu', this.props.menu)
  }

  onSelect = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(item.link)
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainMenu}>
        { (item.icon) && 
          <Image source={item.icon} style={styles.icon} />
        }
        <Text style={styles.txt} onPress={() => this.onSelect(item)}>
          {item.name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <MyHeader />
          <FlatList 
              data = {this.menu}
              renderItem = {this.renderItem}
              keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you navigating from a screen to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling the stacks to not render the header setting:

```
param['headerMode'] = 'none'
```

The `backIcon` you need is rendered inside the `Header`, setting it to "none" will prevent it from appearing.

About the white "line" issue you are talking about, that line is the header you can style and move however you want.

You have to either hide it by yourself globally for the stack, with headerMode set to none, (but this will mean you would have to create your own backButton), style it based off your screen/graphic or hide the header for one specific screen (or show).

For example, imaging you removed the `headerMode: "none"`, you would need to go inside the screen you have the white bar and add:

```
 static navigationOptions = () => {
        return ({ header: null})

    }
```

Inside you react component

Comment: But without I have white space on top of the app, above MyHeader. Even I put marginTop: -50, it didn't disappear, it just reduced the height of my header

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenName)`
2. A back button will automatically appear at the top with header if your stack maintenance is good.

Answer (score 0):

static navigationOptions={header:null} this command use hidding the header,
i think you can remove "param['headerMode'] = 'none'" this code then works fine

Comment: Yah, you're right. But then I have a white space at the top of the application, above the MyHeader. I have checked but there's no marginTop anywhere else ;(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540388/react-native-back-button-missing-icon refer this link may be help you